# How to bind Entity Framework 4 DbSet on DataGridView (windows forms)?

Tags: .net, winforms, entity-framework, binding, datagridview

How to implement CRUD for Entity Framework on windows forms DataGridView optimal? With drop-down DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ?

Comment: I found solution here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aconrad/archive/2007/09/07/science-project.aspx